# CORS in Laravel when using fetch to download a file on storage on localhost

Tags: laravel, cors

Sorry if it looks like I again ask for CORS-configuration in Laravel. But my scenario is alittle bit different and I couldn't find anything helpful yet.

I'm serving my Laravel-Application via `php artisan serve --port 80`

CORS is configured like this in `config/cors.php`:

```
return [
  'paths' => ["*"],
  'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
  'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
  'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
  'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
  'exposed_headers' => [],
  'max_age' => 0,
  'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

And enabled in middleware in `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...

    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    
    // ...
];
```

In my frontend (localhost:8080) I do a simple

`const content = await fetch("http://localhost/storage/plans/46718040-5c72-4999-865f-5174a7c59313.png")`

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/storage/plans/46718040-5c72-4999-865f-5174a7c59313.png'
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Do I have to setup Nginx locally to configure cors for the storage? Or are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to setup Nginx locally to configure cors for the storage?

Yes. Your request isn't invoking Laravel at all, the file is being served statically.

Do you need to use `fetch` to get the content, or can you just set an image source to the file path instead?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of my assumption. "Sadly" I have to use `fetch`...
And I just read, that there's no way to configure CORS for the built in PHP server (which is used via `php artisan server`). Is there?